# Is it possible to use --ignore-matching-lines option with TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm looking for a way to filter out non-relevant, automatically generated changes in my project files. Each file has a generation date in its header.
Because of that, Git marks it as modified. I managed to achieve what I needed using the GITs `--ignore-matching-lines` option, but I'm looking for a way to filter them in TortoiseGIT "check for modifications..." window. Is there a way to achieve that?

Example header:

```
/*
 * File: xxx
 *
 * generated: Thu Dec  7 15:13:38 2023
 *
 */
```

Working git command in windows CMD:

```bash
git diff --ignore-matching-lines=" \* generated: .+"
```